# F# function to split lists failing on empty list

Tags: list, f#

**Edit** I've left the original post here, but have a much simpler reproduction below.

I've been working through a tutorial on F# and I'm at a section where we're implementing a basic mergesort. The first component is to build a split function to turn a list into a 2-tuple of lists formed by splitting the input.

I spent a while on my own and searched online before turning to the tutorial solutions. Everything that I've found fails when splitting and empty list, with the same error.

```
error FS0030: Value restriction. The value 'it' has
been inferred to have generic type
    val it : '_a list * '_a list
Either define 'it' as a simple data term, make it a
function with explicit arguments or, if you do not
intend for it to be generic, add a type annotation
```

All the functions I can come up with and find have a type signature as follows which seems right (some of the samples take an argument for the point at which to split but can be refactored to this)

```
val split : list:'a list -> 'a list * 'a list
```

The error makes it clear that this is something to do with types, but I am clueless at this point. Is it possible in F# to make a well-behaved split function that returns a 2-tuple of empty lists when passed a single empty list?

Would the better solution be to define a type to restrict the domain of split to only be non-empty lists?

Here are some of the things I've tried, and all fail in the same way when called as follows

```
split []
```

My own version

```
let split (list : 'a list) =
    let rec s count head tail =
        match (count, head, tail) with
            | (0, [], []) -> [], []
            | (0, head, tail) -> List.rev head, tail
            | (n, head, x :: tail) -> s (n - 1) (x :: head) tail
    s (list.Length / 2) [] list
```

Two from the [tutorial](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Solutions/Lists#Basic_Mergesort):

```
let rec split = function
| [] -> ([], [])
| [a] -> ([a], [])
| a::b::cs -> let (r, s) = split cs
                in (a::r, b::s)

let split list = List.fold (fun (a,b) c -> (b, c::a)) ([], []) list
```

A version using List.take and List.skip:

```
let split (list : 'a list) =
    let n = list.Length / 2
    List.take n list, List.skip n list
```

**Edit update below**

I've finished up writing the rest of my mergesort and I get a similar error when calling this on an empty list as well.

```
// list: 'a list -> 'a list when 'a : comparison
let rec msort list =
    match list with
    | [] -> []
    | [x] -> [x]
    | x::xs ->
        let head, tail = split (x::xs)
        in merge (msort head, msort tail)
```

When called on the empty list this gives the same error above. The split function isn't even reached in this case.

```
msort []
lists.fsx(2252,1): error FS0030: Value restriction. The
value 'it' has been inferred to have generic type
    val it : '_a list when '_a : comparison
Either define 'it' as a simple data term, make it a
function with explicit arguments or, if you do not
intend for it to be generic, add a type annotation.
```

This made me more curious as it seems like a function with a signature that includes 'a list -> 'a list doesn't work well with an empty list input.

My minimum viable reproduction follows:

```
> List.map (fun x -> x) [];;
lists.fsx(2270,1): error FS0030: Value restriction. The
value 'it' has been inferred to have generic type
    val it : '_a list
Either define 'it' as a simple data term, make it a
function with explicit arguments or, if you do not
intend for it to be generic, add a type annotation.

> List.map (fun x -> x + 1) [];;
val it : int list = []
```

So something is different between a function expecting a specifically typed empty list and something expecting a generically typed empty list.

Can anyone help explain what I (and many examples I can find) are doing wrong in the splitting function above, or explain what's happening in the types that makes an empty typed list behave differently than an empty generically typed list?

Comment: FWIW, running through LINQPad yields no errors.  Perhaps it's just LINQPad suppressing the errors but it runs fine for me as I would expect.

Comment: Interesting. I just downloaded LINQPad and I cannot recreate the issue. I can recreate in FSI in VSCode and in Visual studio, both of which run the following FSI version. Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 14.0.23413.0

Comment: @greggyb: this has already been answered in the linked question. It's mostly an artifact of FSI not having enough type information to resolve the type of the list. You need to provide a type annotation, e.g. `List.map (fun x -> x) ([]: int list)`.

Comment: Thanks much scrwtp. If you want to post that as an answer, I'll mark this question answered. Or how do duplicate questions get handled?